# why sklearn SelectFromModel estimator_.coef_ return a 2d-array

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

My data `df_X` has 11 features and `y` is multi-class label. I used multi-class SVM to select importance of features. `estimator_.coef_` should return the score of each feature. But why here it returns a list of scores? The same case occured for multi-class LogisticRegression().

By the way, what's the difference between `SelectKBest` and `SelectFromModel` for feature selection in sklearn.

[image]

Comment: Do you have 11 classes?

Comment: @Sycorax no, the classes in samples are 3,4,5,6,7,8.